# How to update an array field in laravel?

Tags: laravel, sql-update

**EDIT FORM**

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label>Country:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select  id="country-dd" name="country[]" class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" multiple="multiple">
                        @foreach($countries as $country)
                        <option value="{{$country->id }}" {{in_array($country->id, explode(',',$user->country)) ? 'selected' : '' }}> {{$country->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function updateuser(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // dd($request->all());
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
            'country'=>'required',
            'state'=>'required',
            'city'=>'required',
            'role_id'=>'required'

        ]);
        $name = $request->name;
        $email=$request->email;
        $country=implode(',',$request->country);
        $state=implode(',',$request->state);
        $city=implode(',',$request->city);
        $role_id=$request->role_id;
        
        User::whereId($id)->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('viewuser');
    }
```

**ROUTE**

```
Route::put('/updateuser/{id}',[UserController::class,'updateuser'])->name('updateuser');
```

If I update a record. It just reloads the page and there is no error. Please correct me if I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate more, I can't figure where is the problem from your words.

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan Country field is array. Which means I can store multiple countries. Which is working fine while adding new record. But while updating, It is not working.

Comment: can you show me what is the output of dd($request['country'])

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "1jKq7Ca4ZRkbYmbORU6zSEYsygRTr0p26G23keKZ"
  "name" => "salman"
  "email" => "salman@gmail.com"
  "country" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "38"
    1 => "101"
  ]
  "state" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "12"
    1 => "671"
  ]
  "city" => array:2 [▶]
  "role_id" => "2"
]

Comment: Good , another final step what is the country field in user table looks like, is it a string? if so then you should change this         $country=implode(',',$request->country);
to         $request['country']=implode(',',$request->country);

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan Still not working. It just reloads the page. But data is not updated.

Comment: Please update the question itself with the user model and table schema, and let us see how it is done in storing and works

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan I am not able to edit question. Please find below method in user model.
public function countries(){
        return $this->FindInSetMany(Country::class, 'country', 'id');
    }

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan 
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('country');
            $table->string('state');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->bigInteger('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('restrict');
            // $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

Comment: is in user model, country added in fillable array?

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan yes It is added

Comment: I missed this line: User::whereId($id)
 It should be User::whereId($id)->first() or easily use User::find($id)

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan Still not working

Comment: That's wired. show my your try that did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in the CONTROLLER:

```
public function updateuser(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
            'country'=>'required',
            'state'=>'required',
            'city'=>'required',
            'role_id'=>'required'

        ]);
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email=$request->email;
        $user->country=implode(',',$request->country);
        $user->state=implode(',',$request->state);
        $user->city=implode(',',$request->city);
        $user->role_id=$request->role_id;
        $user->update();
       
        return redirect()->route('viewuser');
    }
```

Try in the form:

```
<form action="{{ route('updateuser',$data->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf


    ALL YOUR INPUTS HERE


    <div class="card-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-1 pr-4 pl-4">Update</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Route

```
Route::match(['put', 'patch'], 'updateuser/{id}', [UserController::class,'updateuser'])->name('updateuser');
```

Comment: I changed this in controller. But its still not working. Can you check route ?? And also tell me form method

Comment: Check now. updated answer

Comment: It is showing below error
The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: maybe you missed @method('PUT') in form

Comment: It is there in form. And route method is post.

Comment: Answer updated. Route added. Please check

Comment: Made changes in rote. But still not working. It just reloads the page.

Comment: Can you please check and update

Comment: In controller, remove unique for email field

Comment: What's the error now?

Comment: Its done now. I mentioned in previous comment. (Removing unique in email field). Thank you